# 100% width div for browser width

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to add two divs inside the parent div, which has a button inside each div.
I need to fix the width in pixels only for the second div and the 1st div should be having width in % so that the button inside the 1st div should be covering the entire space of the browser.

I need all the widths in % and also I don't want to change either html structure and css because it is already implemented so i just need changes in css property.

Here is my demo
http://jsfiddle.net/zuyyT/2/

P.S : When I scale the browser, the second div is coming in next line. Please scale it and check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle is working on and off ... you can go either one of two ways; using floats (need to change the order of your markup) or positioning - like such ...

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block_right"><a href=""> <span>last button</span></a> </div>
    <div class="block_left"><a href="" class="scButton score" > <span>Lorem ipsum</span></a></div>
</div>
```

and your CSS ...

```
.block {
    display:block; background-color:#FFC; width:100%; float:left; height:30px
}
.block_left{
    background-color:#C93; margin-right: 150px;  
}
.block_left a{
    background-color:#CCC; border-radius:4px; padding:4px; width:100%; display:block
}
.block_right{
    float:right; width:130px; background-color:#CC9
}
```

... using position, you'll need to add `position:relative` to .block and then `right:0` to .block_right; keep the margin on .block_left

Using positioning, you won't need to change the order of the elements in your markup (should that be an issue).

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you require. :-)

```
.block_right{
    position :absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    float:right; width:130px; background-color:#CC9
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give your `block_left` a `width:100%` and then use `margin-right:-130px;` you can leave your html exactly as it is.

The negative right margin leaves space on the right hand side for other elements to fit into even though the element has a 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the width of right div..u gave 100% to the parent and 80% to the first child..so,when the browser size is 500px(say),the first child will occupy 400px(80%) of it...And when u give 130 px to the second child,it'll come to the next line..that's pretty obvious coz it doesn't have enough space in the first line...so it should be <=100px(for this example)...